IVsSccGlyphs2 didn't call GetCustomGlyphMonikerList() when the project(.net version) is loading
I am developing a VSIX project.
When loading the project, the IVsSccGlyphs2 interface calls the GetCustomGlyphMonikerList member to apply all the badges in the Solution Explorer.
However, when debugging a VSIX project, if the solution running is the .net framework version, the GetCustomGlyphMonikerList member is called when loading the project,
but the GetCustomGlyphMonikerList member is not called for the .net version. (It seems to be a bug that does not work only when loading the project, since it works when making changes to the solution explorer after loading the project.)
I don't know if that's a bug in Microsoft..
Can you tell me why? If it can be solved, how can I do it?
Thank you :)
I checked and changed Nuget package's version (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.....Etc....)
And I checked "Version Compatibility" between .Net version and .Net Framework version because VSIX Project is .Net Framework version...
